# how do i get nearby Instagram pictures using Instagram API

Tags: cordova, instagram, ionic-framework, instagram-api

I'm doing an android app which pulls nearby Instagram pictures using geolocation, is there any API from Instagram ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET /media/search/ endpoint in the Instagram API for retrieving media by location. You provide the latitude, longitude and distance from that point using the endpoint.

Please read the Instagram API documentation: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_search